# Error while deploying Django application with Gunicorn?

Tags: python, linux, django, gunicorn, systemd

I tried to deploy a django app using ngnix-gunicorn like here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04
I did it without virtualenv. Here is the 'gunicorn.service' file.
When I tried to make a systemd, I facing an error.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
Environment=SECRET_KEY='*uj$'
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/myproject
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is here is the error while creating a systemd.

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-08-26 14:05:19 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 24747 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/test1/test1.sock test1.wsgi:applica
 Main PID: 24747 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Aug 26 14:05:19 ip-172-31-1-229 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Aug 26 14:05:19 ip-172-31-1-229 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Aug 26 14:05:19 ip-172-31-1-229 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 26 14:05:19 ip-172-31-1-229 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: It looks like you are not specifying the WSGI (django) app that gunicorn should start. gunicorn must be started as `gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE` and you seem to be missing the `APP_MODULE` part. See the docs: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html

Comment: Can you put the gunicorn logs here? I can see that it tried to run the gunicorn but exit.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the gunicorn with supervisord. It works amazingly fine with the below configuration.

```
[program:analytics]
command = /home/ubuntu/code/analytics/bin/gunicorn example.wsgi:application --name example --workers 4 --user=ubuntu --timeout=3600 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000
user = ubuntu ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/code/example/current/slog/gunicorn_start.log  ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true     ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/code/current/example/bin/python ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

You may try installing supervisord as pip and include the above configuration into it with include parameter of supervisord.conf.

For more information: http://supervisord.org/